# Getting errors while compiling Irrlicht for Android

Tags: android, irrlicht

While compiling the android port of Irrlicht 3d engine:
https://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid
I get the following errors:

```
    I:/Developments/irrlichtandroid/project/obj/local/armeabi/objs/irrlicht/COGLES2Driver.o:I:\Developments\irrlichtandroid\project\jni/./../include/IReferenceCounted.h:54: multiple definition of `GL_BGRA'
    I:/Developments/irrlichtandroid/project/obj/local/armeabi/objs/irrlicht/COGLESDriver.o:I:\Developments\irrlichtandroid\project\jni/./../include/IReferenceCounted.h:54: first defined here
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this conflict ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found on a comment of this thread:
http://renzhi.ca/2011/05/19/programming-3d-games-on-android-with-irrlicht-and-bullet-part-1/

In IrrCompileConfig.h:
comment out one of the following lines:

```
#define _IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OGLES2_
```

or

```
#define _IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OGLES1_
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~